# C/C++: Taking the address of a function imported from a shared library

Tags: c++, c, linker, shared-libraries, elf

I recently learnt of PLT/GOT in ELF, and am now confused: how are addresses-of-imported-functions taken and stored into function pointers?

I tested and two addresses-of-an-imported-function taken at different shared libraries are indeed equal (as the standard requires), but this seems to require some magic I don't understand.

These can't be the addresses of the PLT slots, as they are different for different shared libs. These also can't be the address at the exporting library, as this is resolved (by default) only after the function is actually called.

What am I missing?

The question is phrased in Linux context, but the same could be asked about windows and IAT slots.  Also, not sure about the 'linkers' tag but I suspect it might be relevant.

Comment: Functions in a shared library are accessed through a jump table. When the shared library is mounted, a link is done between these jumps and the address of each functions. Taking the address of a function returns the address of its corresponding jump.

Comment: Relocations resolved dynamically at load time. Drepper writes about it in http://library.bagrintsev.me/CPP/dsohowto.pdf. Taking global addresses and storing them such that they could be compared later adds to loadtime because of these loadtime relocatoins. Just calling a function doesn't at to loadtime because it can be resolved lazily via the PLT.

Comment: @dalfaB On Linux I believe there are 2 such tables: the PLT and the GOT. And as noted at the question, by default neither contain the actual function address until it is called.

Comment: @PSkocik reading through Drepper's paper is what triggerred this question. Not sure I understand your comment: are you suggesting that merely taking a function address somehow changes the way it is imported? (e.g. causes the equivalent of LD_BIND_NOW for its entry?)

Comment: Yes, taking a function address in ways that could result in later address comparisons changes the way it's imported by marking it with a special relocation. Ian Lance Taylor also mentions it in https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/42.

Comment: @PSkocik thanks!  Your link says "[The function is] marked as undefined but with a non-zero value – the value will be set to the address of the PLT entry. When the dynamic linker is searching for the value of a symbol to use for a reloc [...], if it finds such a specially marked symbol, it will use the non-zero value. This will ensure that all references to the symbol which are not function calls will use the same value. "  - can you see how is this a solution? If the value used is "the address of the PLT entry" it is still different for different shared libraries, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by creating an example:

```
// foo.c
int foo() { return 42; }

// bar.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo();
int bar()
{
  printf(" %s:%d: &foo = %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, &foo);
  return foo();
}

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo();
extern int bar();
int main()
{
  printf("%s:%d: &foo = %p\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, &foo);
  return bar();
}
```

Build it with:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c &&
gcc -g -fPIC -shared -o bar.so bar.c &&
gcc -g main.c ./bar.so ./foo.so -no-pie
```

(the `-no-pie` is not necessary, but makes it easier to debug).

```
$ ./a.out
main.c:7: &foo = 0x7f3d66a180f9
 bar.c:6: &foo = 0x7f3d66a180f9
```

It worked. Now we are ready to answer "how does the magic happen?".

First let's examine `main` disassembly:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401136 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401137 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040113a <+4>:     mov    0x2e9f(%rip),%rax        # 0x403fe0
   0x0000000000401141 <+11>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x0000000000401144 <+14>:    mov    $0x7,%edx
   0x0000000000401149 <+19>:    lea    0xeb4(%rip),%rax        # 0x402004
   0x0000000000401150 <+26>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000401153 <+29>:    lea    0xeb1(%rip),%rax        # 0x40200b
   0x000000000040115a <+36>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040115d <+39>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401162 <+44>:    callq  0x401040 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000401167 <+49>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040116c <+54>:    callq  0x401030 <bar@plt>
   0x0000000000401171 <+59>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401172 <+60>:    retq
```

Here we can see that the last argument to `printf` comes from loading a value at address `0x403fe0`. What is at that address?

```
readelf -WS a.out | grep '\.got'
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000403fd0 002fd0 000018 08  WA  0   0  8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000403fe8 002fe8 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
```

Apparently that address is `&.got[2]`. How does the value and up there? Back to GDB:

```
(gdb) watch *(void**)0x403fe0
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(void**)0x403fe0
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/shlib/a.out

Hardware watchpoint 1: *(void**)0x403fe0

Old value = (void *) 0x0
New value = (void *) 0x7ffff7fba0f9
elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=<optimized out>, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, scope=<optimized out>, map=0x7ffff7ffe2e0) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:408
408     ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=<optimized out>, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, scope=<optimized out>, map=0x7ffff7ffe2e0) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:408
#1  _dl_relocate_object (l=l@entry=0x7ffff7ffe2e0, scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=<optimized out>, consider_profiling=<optimized out>, consider_profiling@entry=0) at ./elf/dl-reloc.c:301
#2  0x00007ffff7fe8c09 in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=<optimized out>, user_entry=<optimized out>, auxv=<optimized out>) at ./elf/rtld.c:2322
#3  0x00007ffff7fe519f in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=start_argptr@entry=0x7fffffffd960, dl_main=dl_main@entry=0x7ffff7fe6e10 <dl_main>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-sysdep.c:140
#4  0x00007ffff7fe6b1c in _dl_start_final (arg=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffd8c8>) at ./elf/rtld.c:497
#5  _dl_start (arg=<optimized out>) at ./elf/rtld.c:584
#6  0x00007ffff7fe59c8 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

So the runtime loader put the value there as part of relocating the `a.out` (in frame#1 you can see that `l->addr == 0` and `l->name == ""`, which correspond to the main executable).

What caused the loader to resolve `foo` without it being called?

```
readelf -Wr a.out | egrep 'foo|bar'
0000000000403fe0  0000000500000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 foo + 0
0000000000404000  0000000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT     0000000000000000 bar + 0
```

Here you can see that calling a function (`bar` here) and taking address of a function (`foo` here) results in *different* relocation records.

The `JUMP` relocation can be resolved lazily (when the function is called), but `GLOB_DAT` can not. The loader has to resolve all `GLOB_DAT` relocations at load time, and it does.

Likewise, in `bar.so` we have:

```
gdb -q ./bar.so
(gdb) disas bar
   0x0000000000001109 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000110a <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000110d <+4>:     mov    0x2ebc(%rip),%rax        # 0x3fd0
   0x0000000000001114 <+11>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x0000000000001117 <+14>:    mov    $0x6,%edx
   0x000000000000111c <+19>:    lea    0xedd(%rip),%rax        # 0x2000
...

readelf -Wr bar.so | grep foo
0000000000003fd0  0000000400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 foo + 0

readelf -WS bar.so | grep '\.got'
  [11] .plt.got          PROGBITS        0000000000001040 001040 000010 08  AX  0   0  8
  [20] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000003fc0 002fc0 000028 08  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000003fe8 002fe8 000020 08  WA  0   0  8
```

so the `&foo` is filled in `&bar.so:.got[2]` at load time as well.

P.S. We can also look in the output from `readelf -Wr a.out bar.so` to see what other relocations are present and why `&foo` is filled in the third slot of the GOT:

```
File: a.out

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x4f0 contains 3 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000403fd0  0000000100000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34 + 0
0000000000403fd8  0000000400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
0000000000403fe0  0000000500000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 foo + 0
...

File: bar.so

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x3f8 contains 8 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
0000000000003df0  0000000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                         1100
0000000000003df8  0000000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                         10c0
0000000000004008  0000000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                         4008
0000000000003fc0  0000000100000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable + 0
0000000000003fc8  0000000300000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
0000000000003fd0  0000000400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 foo + 0
0000000000003fd8  0000000500000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTable + 0
0000000000003fe0  0000000600000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT      0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

The fact that both relocation records happened to address the third slot in `.got` is a coincidence -- the slots could easily be different.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research! I recently came across this quote from the SystemV ABI (https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/x86-64-ABI/abi.pdf?job=build): "To allow comparisons of function addresses to work as expected, if an executable file references a function defined in a shared object, the link editor will place the address of the procedure linkage table entry for that function in its associated symbol table entry...".  This seems to be a different valid solution to the comparison problem - you're saying this is not the case today?